# How to search json using key and value and remove all matched entries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am having Json this way,

```
[
{
    "y": "2014",
    "m": "1313",
    "rowKey": "2014_13",
    "key": "m",
    "value": "13   "
},
{
    "y": "2014",
    "m": "1313",
    "rowKey": "2014_13_1",
    "key": "m",
    "value": "13   "
},
{
    "y": "2014",
    "m": "1313",
    "rowKey": "2014_13_2",
    "key": "m",
    "value": "13   "
}
```

]

I tried removing the entries from the json based on key and value I pass as input, this way,

```
function findAndRemove(array, property, value) {

    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        delete array[i].y;
        delete array[i].m;
        delete array[i].rowKey;
        delete array[i].key;
        delete array[i].value;
    }
}
```

My Removed json is this way,`[{},{},{}]`

where i want it to be this way, Removed Json  [].

I.e, remove complete entry from the JSon, not only the keys and values.

I also tried this  way,

```
    function findAndRemove(array, property, value) {
    $.each(array, function(index, result) {
        if(undefined != result[property] && result[property] == value && array.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            //Remove from array
            array.splice(index, 1);
        }    
    });
}
```

which is giving indexing issues.

I will pass key and value then it should remove the complete entry from json,

ex: if i pass rowKey,2014_13 it should remove below entry from json

```
 [{"y":"2014","m":"1313","rowKey":"2014_13","key":"m","value":"13   "}]
```

if entries are duplicated this way,

```
 [{"y":"2014","m":"1313","rowKey":"2014_13","key":"m","value":"13   "}, [{"y":"2014","m":"1313","rowKey":"2014_13","key":"m","value":"13   "}]
```

then it should remove both the entries.

Basically search the json for key and value passed and remove all the matched entries.
Can  anyone help me in this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Here is an example of using it:

```
var data = [{
    "y": "2014",
    "m": "1313",
    "rowKey": "2014_13",
    "key": "m",
    "value": "13   "
}, {
    "y": "2014",
    "m": "1313",
    "rowKey": "2014_13_1",
    "key": "m",
    "value": "13   "
}, {
    "y": "2014",
    "m": "1313",
    "rowKey": "2014_13_2",
    "key": "m",
    "value": "13   "
}];

var good = data.filter(function(record) {
    return record['rowKey'] !== '2014_13';
});

console.log(good);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vbxLpwo/